# channel 0/1 got hung up in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr

I am trying to make a outgoing from an asterisk pbx using .call file but every time .call file is moved in outgoing folder my cli shows

```
[Jun 16 15:38:12] NOTICE[30435]: pbx_spool.c:372 attempt_thread: Call failed to go through, reason (1) Hangup
[Jun 16 15:38:12] NOTICE[30435]: pbx_spool.c:375 attempt_thread: Queued call to DAHDI/g0/09716927126 expired without completion after 0 attempts
    -- Span 1: Channel 0/1 got hangup request, cause 16
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/09711590094-103a'
[Jun 16 15:38:17] NOTICE[30434]: pbx_spool.c:372 attempt_thread: Call failed to go through, reason (1) Hangup
[Jun 16 15:38:17] NOTICE[30434]: pbx_spool.c:375 attempt_thread: Queued call to DAHDI/g0/09711590094 expired without completion after 0 attempts
    -- Attempting call on DAHDI/g0/09711590094 for 4759509@outgoing1:1 (Retry 1)
    -- Attempting call on DAHDI/g0/09716927126 for 4759509@outgoing1:1 (Retry 1)
    -- Requested transfer capability: 0x00 - SPEECH
    -- Requested transfer capability: 0x00 - SPEECH
    -- Span 1: Channel 0/2 got hangup request, cause 31
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/09716927126-103d'
```

my **.call** file

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/09711590094
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 600
WaitTime: 30
Context: outgoing1
Extension: 10
Priority: 1
```

The call could not be connected.Anybody knows what would be the possible reason for that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of your call file here?  That would be helpful.

Comment: updated my call file @MichelV69

Comment: Ok.  Create an extension in your dialplan as follows:

exten => _999,1,Dial(DAHDI/g0/09711590094) 

... and tell me what happens when you dial 999 from a local extension.  Of course, if 999 is already in use, please change it to something else appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This error mean you can't call as requested via dahdi/g0

Very likly you  have configure correctly your dahdi card.